# Show Popup in .Net Maui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am trying to use the .Net Maui community toolkit to show a Popup as a loading page when computing in page and between pages. However when I execute the code it does not show the popup on the device using this.ShowPopUpAsync(popup) or Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup).

My PopUp Xaml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           x:Class="DailyBudgetMAUIApp.Handlers.PopUpPage"
           xmlns:xct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Color="Transparent">
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Margin="0,100,0,0" Color="{DynamicResource Primary}" Scale="1">
            </ActivityIndicator>
            <Label Text="Loading ..." FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold" TextColor="{DynamicResource Light}" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

With the Xaml.cs

```
public partial class PopUpPage : Popup
{
    public PopUpPage()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then I am calling a method where I want to show the popup in something like this

```
private async void UndoCreateBudget(int BudgetID)
{
    Popup popup = new PopUpPage();
    await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
    

    //Call my api and do some stuff


    popup.Close();

}
```

Comment: Why not use a [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) ? When starting computing, send a message to open the popup, when finishing computing, send a message to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The Popup is valid.
And using this way to call it - it will show up.

Tested it on Android and Windows. I am almost certain that if you place a breakpoint in this method: `UndoCreateBudget` it will never get hit at first place. So you should check this first.

Anyway, I am not writing this to tell you it will work. You have a deadlock right there.

This line:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
```

Will very tricky lure you to await it, when you hover over it. And it does not take into consideration that you have this line in the xaml:

```
CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
```

You have to run this task. Run it, not await it. It waits for the popup to close. And this kind of popup you have will never close on its own.

You will never get to the API call. And you will lock your interface.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried running it with both Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup) and Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(popup). Neither seem to work, they will work if I never close them it shows up after I have navigated to the next page or have completed the action but not while I am doing it. Is there something really obvious I am missing here?

Comment: @DarrenFillis Nope. Everything works fine. If you have problems - they are not in those parts of code you posted. Show me where you call UndoCreateBudget.

Comment: I had a play about and have been able to get the popup to show, but it is only showing after I call an await GoToAsync() method, and only on occasion. I call UndoCreateBudget inside of my Xaml.cs File, it is attached to a snackbar button using action = async () => await UndoCreateBudget(_vm.SnackID); It also doesnt seem to work really anywhere, tried in my Xaml.cs, in my view model and in lots of places within it and can't get it work. I guess worth mentioning I am running on .Net8 preview but tried looking about for a defect like this raised and can't find anything so unsure?

Comment: @DarrenFillis If you upload some sample project to github, that demonstrates your issue, I will update my home setup to 8.0 and test it. Otherwise there is nothing else I can say about it. The code is correct, it is working perfectly on my side. (Emulator, Device, PC.)

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest another way of loading data. Use a Modal Window. You don't get that grayed out background that can be a bit off putting to some users, and you get a reusable View for all kinds of API calls. This means you do the API calls in the loading view and not in the Content View. Then again you can send an event that trigger when the loading is opened, so there are possibilities for that too.

```cs
public class LoadingPage : ContentPage
{
    private ActivityIndicator _indicator;
    private VerticalStackLayout _stackLayout;

    public LoadingPage()
    {
        BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1);

        _indicator = new ActivityIndicator
        {
            IsRunning = true,
            Color = Colors.Black,
            Scale = 1,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        var loadingLabel = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Loading...",
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        _stackLayout = new VerticalStackLayout
        {
            WidthRequest = 200,
            HeightRequest = 300,
            BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1),
            Children =
            {
                _indicator,
                loadingLabel
            }
        };

        Content = _stackLayout;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await Dismiss();
    }

    public async Task Dismiss()
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        _indicator.IsRunning = false;
        _stackLayout.IsVisible = false;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        // Return true to prevent the back button from closing the page
        return true;
    }
}
```

You call it from your method like this

```cs
var page = new LoadingPage();
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, false);
```

Here is a sample how it can look like

[image]

Comment: I get an issue when I set await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, false) the animation to false it doesn't show the loading at all, any ideas?

Comment: Does the page show at all? Is it the text or the ActivityIndicator that doesn't show?

Answer (score 0):

I am here to share another way of using [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0) to display and dismiss popup for your scenario.

First, [Publish a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0#publish-a-message)

```
private async void UndoCreateBudget(int BudgetID)
{
    Popup popup = new PopUpPage();
    await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
    
    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "display");
    //Call my api and do some stuff

    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "dismiss");
}
```

Then [Subscribe to a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0#subscribe-to-a-message)

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "start", (e) =>
    {

        popup = new PopUpPage();
        this.ShowPopup(popup);
    });

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "close", (e) =>
    {
        popup.Close();
    });
}
```

For .NET MAUI 7, you could use [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger)